# Selecting a div within in a div

Tags: jquery, html

Apologies for simple question I am just starting out.
I have a navigation div and 4 button class divs inside it.

I want to be able to change background class for the appropriate button div when mouseover/enter etc.

This is the Jquery I have so far

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).stop(true,true).find(".button").fadeTo(200,0.5,function(){
    $("#nav").mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).stop(true,true).find(".button").fadeTo(200,1);
    });
   });
  });
 }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: What is the question? What problems do you have?

Comment: Set up your code on jsfiddle.com, post the link and we can suggest a better way to do it

Comment: My main problem is selecting a div within a div then fading a css property of that selected div when mouseEnter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav .button").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo(200,0.5,function(){
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo(200,1);
    });
   });
  });
 }); 
 </script>
```

I don't know what this does nor have tested it, but the point is I think you want to add the event handlers to the buttons themselves, not the container. Is that so?

Comment: Thanks Victor this gives me the effect I want. The .mouseenter string shows me how to do it from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#nav').find('.button').each(function(){
    $(this).mouseover(function(){
        $(this).attr('style', 'background:url(http://jsfiddle.net/favicon.gif) top left');
    });
    $(this).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).attr('style', 'background:none');
    });
});
```

You can see it working here - http://jsfiddle.net/FDQXa/

Comment: Hi Alex can you make the background Gif fadeIn? My main problem was selecting divs within in divs etc.